# How should I write a pointcut expression for an inner class?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm trying to use AOP to profile methods in a data-access class. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
package com.example.dataservices.dao;

public class DaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements Dao
{
    protected static abstract class CallbackHandler
    {
        abstract void processRow(final ResultSet rset);

        abstract DataPayload getPayload();

        boolean isCompanyPermitted(final Long companyId)
        {
            return true;
        }

        boolean isUserPermitted(final Long userId)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected static class CompanyCallbackHandler extends CallbackHandler
    {
        DataPayload payload;

        void processRow(final ResultSet rset)
        {
            if (isUserPermitted(rset.getlong(1))) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }

        DataPayload getPayload(final Long companyId)
        {
            this.payload = new DataPayload();
            // query the database
            return this.payload;
        }
    }

    public DataPayload getCompanyPayload(final Long companyId)
    {

        final CallbackHandler handler = new CompanyCallbackHandler();
        return handler.getPayload(companyId);
    }
}
```

My pointcut expression looks like this:

> @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.dataservices.dao..*.*(..))")

But this expression only matches the getCompanyPayload() method. I'm trying to match methods like the isUserPermitted() that CompanyCallbackHandler inherits from its parent class CallbackHandler.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Are you using Spring AOP or AspectJ?

Answer (score 0):

I supose that you are using AspectJ, with Spring AOP don't have any posibilities.

on execution poincut the qualifing type is the type that declared the method so

`execution(* com.example.dataservice.dao..*.*(..))` will pick any execution on package dao in class or inner-class if the method is **declared**  or **overriden** in that class. Inheritance is not enough.

Comment: Thanks - I think you've identified the problem. After repeated rebuilds and also refactoring the target code to remove the inner classes, I finally discovered that Spring AOP only works on public methods of classes that are instantiated as Spring beans. I can understand the reasons for this, but it's a pretty severe limitation, and I think it could be made clearer in the Spring documentation.

Comment: wow, glad that I read this! a really good reason to use Aspectj by itself as I was pkanning. I love Spring Environment and will as much of bn it asn posssible. But apparently not AOP.